# Converting UniqueIdentifier to Hex string

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-nifi

My table has a binary GGUID field. The hex Value of this field is `0x222134A61766432BAC3CA2D8C8058751`.

In nifi ExecuteSQL binary fields are stored in byte-arrays

```
{
  "GGUID" : [ 34, 33, 52, -90, 23, 102, 67, 43, -84, 60, -94, -40, -56, 5, -121, 81 ]
}
```

I found a lot of CAST and CONVERT functions for GGUI

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(nvarchar(36), GGUID) AS nGuid,
  CONVERT(bigint, GGUID) AS iGuid,
  CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, GGUID) AS uGuid,
  CONVERT(binary(16), GGUID) AS bGuid,
  CAST(GGUID AS VARCHAR(36)) AS vGuid,
  GGUID
FROM [dbo].[ADDRESS0]
```

but non of them is returning a hex string.

Result in SSMS (SSMS is displaying binary data in hex format):
[image: result in SSMS]

Question:

Do you now a function/cast/convert for converting a binary field to a hex string?

P.S.: And yes: I've got a solution: building the hex string on my own in a script

Comment: Can you provide an example where you show the normal guid value and the desired hex result.

Comment: while I understand what you're asking, the use case is not clear. the binary(16) representation of UNIQUEIDENTIFIER already is what you need (it being an array just like in nifi). what are you really attempting to convert from/to?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can create a JSON string in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the [CONVERT() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

You can do it in a single statement, but cast the uniqueidentifier to a varbinary value and then convert it to a varchar using style 1 if you want the `0x` prefix, or style 2 if you don't, e.g.:

```sql
declare @uGuid uniqueidentifier = 'A6342122-6617-2B43-AC3C-A2D8C8058751';
declare @varbinary varbinary(16) = cast(@uGuid as varbinary(16));

select
  @uGuid, -- A6342122-6617-2B43-AC3C-A2D8C8058751
  @varbinary, -- 0x222134A61766432BAC3CA2D8C8058751
  convert(varchar(50), @varbinary, 1), -- '0x222134A61766432BAC3CA2D8C8058751'
  convert(varchar(50), @varbinary, 2) -- '222134A61766432BAC3CA2D8C8058751'
```